# Sonar throws NullPointerException when analyzing Java Annotation class file

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar throws NullPointerException when analyzing the following Java Annotation class file:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
    String description() default "MyAnnotation";

    int order() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    boolean continueOnFailure() default false;
}
```

Stack track:

```
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5] Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/media/ebs_data0/data/TeamCity/buildAgents/1/work/6863f0261204b044/..../MyAnnotation.java'
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:115)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.scan(AstScanner.java:76)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:136)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:129)
.......
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     ... 22 more
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.sonar.java.checks.LeftCurlyBraceStartLineCheck.visitNode(LeftCurlyBraceStartLineCheck.java:43)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.visitNode(AstWalker.java:114)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.visit(AstWalker.java:85)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.visitChildren(AstWalker.java:99)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.visit(AstWalker.java:87)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.visitChildren(AstWalker.java:99)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.visit(AstWalker.java:87)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.walkAndVisit(AstWalker.java:69)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:108)
[21:43:44] :     [Step 5/5]     ... 58 more
```

Sonar was invoked via `mvn sonar:sonar -X` in our Teamcity server to generate the above stack traces.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I searched for this and found that this is a bug in 2.5 http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-758. However, you can follow http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/SQ-4-5-1-Cannot-analyze-annotated-interface-td5029741.html. Probably might help.

Comment: @AnveshVejandla Our Sonar is exactly 2.5! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnveshVejandla Hey, I was unable to find 2.6 version anywhere. Could you point out where it is? Thanks!

Comment: search Maven Repository. http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=sonar